# Pygame Rectangle Doesn't Appear Unless I Tab-out and Back In

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I've got this code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)

class setup():
    def set_resolution(x, y):
        global surf
        global screen
        surf = pygame.Surface((x,y))
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Lewis' Game")
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(200,150,150,50))

    def menu():
        pass

setup.set_resolution(1024,768)
setup.menu()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

For some reason, the `pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(200,150,150,50))` at the end of the setup function doesn't actually appear unless I show the desktop and them tab back in. I'm not sure why this is happening as it's never happened before. I should mention that I'm still learning pygame, and this code is just for practice.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call `pygame.display.update()` for anything to draw.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `while` loop to include this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip()    # pygame.display.update works as well
```

if you want more on the difference of these, see [Difference between pygame.display.update and pygame.display.flip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314987/difference-between-pygame-display-update-and-pygame-display-flip)

Comment: I see! I hadn't been familiar with `.flip()` before. Thank you!